# Working Iterative formula for a system of equations

Tags: matrix, iteration

I have been given a project, I need to show the use of a version of Newton's method to solve these non-linear equations. The version of Newton's method I am required to use is: $ X_{n+1} = X_n - J^{(-1)} F(X_n) $. I have all the values required here, and this works to find the point $ X_1 $. However I need to find a code that inputs the following points $ X_2, X_3, ..., X_n $ automatically. Here are the given values:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 5;
g[x_, y_] := x^3 - y^3 - 7;

x0 = 2.1;
y0 = 0.9;

f[x0, y0]
g[x0, y0]
```

> 0.22
>
> 1.532

```
M = {{2*x0, 2*y0}, {3*x0^2, -3*y0^2}}
```

> {{4.2, 1.8}, {13.23, -2.43}}

```
J = Inverse[M]
```

> {{0.0714286, 0.0529101}, {0.388889, -0.123457}}

```
F0 = {{f[x0, y0]}, {g[x0, y0]}}
X0 = {{x0}, {y0}}
X1 = X0 - J.F0
```

> {{0.22}, {1.532}}
>   {{2.1}, {0.9}}
>   {{2.00323}, {1.00358}}

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Have a look at `FixedPoint` and `FixedPointList` and their option `SameTest`. `Nest(List)` and `NestWhile(List)` also come to mind. You can also use `FindRoot` which has all this built-in.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will try some of the commands you have listed. Unfortunately, FindRoot does not help me in my situation as I need to show all the iterations leading up to the point, rather than just find the point itself.

Comment: Oh, this can also be done with `FindRoot`: Try `Reap[FindRoot[Sin[x] == 0.2, {x, Pi/42}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]]`. Btw.: Using `LinearSolve` instead of `Inverse` should be faster for larger systems and should prevent certain problems with precision loss.

Answer (score 2):

```
jac = D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, y}, 1}];
Xlist = NestList[# - Inverse[jac /. Thread[{x, y} -> #]].{f @@ #, g @@ #} &, {x0, y0}, 5]
```

> {{2.1, 0.9}, {2.0032275, 1.0035802}, {2.0000033, 1.0000051}, {2., 1.}, {2., 1.}, {2., 1.}}

You can get the same from `FindRoot`:

```
{res, {steps}} = Reap[FindRoot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, x0}, {y, y0}}, 
                       Method -> "Newton", StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]]]
```

> {{x -> 2., y -> 1.}, {{{2.0032275, 1.0035802}, {2.0000033, 1.0000051}, {2., 1.}, {2., 1.}}}}

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

I'll show it with FixedPointList

```
f[x_, y_] = {x^2 + y^2 - 5, x^3 - y^3 - 7};
j[x_, y_] = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
```

with LinearSolve:

```
FixedPointList[(# - LinearSolve[j[Sequence @@ #], f[Sequence @@ #]]) &, {2.1, 0.9}, 3]
{{2.1, 0.9}, {2.00323, 1.00358}, {2., 1.00001}, {2., 1.}}
```

with Inverse:

```
FixedPointList[(# - Inverse[j[Sequence @@ #]].f[Sequence @@ #]) &, {2.1, 0.9}, 3]
{{2.1, 0.9}, {2.00323, 1.00358}, {2., 1.00001}, {2., 1.}}
```